# Google's cache is not updated for months and doesn't match "fetch as Google"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-cache

I used webmaster's Fetch as Google tool to see how my website looks on Google.
The snapshot of rendered page returned by Google is exactly same as my website so I submitted it for indexing.

Logically Google's cached copy of this URL should have been updated by Google but it didn't change and now it's been almost 6 months since the last change. Here is URL for cached copy of this above Page: `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com`

It is not happening with all pages. A few pages are being cached properly. Just to give you an idea, this URL is cached properly: `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:paintcollar.com/aneel`

What is the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Remove Outdated Content tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1) in Search Console. Submit the URL and click through the dialogue box:

1. Has the page been removed or updated? Yes.
2. Click "Next", and select "The snippet and cache are outdated."

Sometimes this issue can be traced to a specific cause, but often it's simply a glitch on Google's part. I suspect the latter's the case here.

Comment: Thanks @Gdav..... Just wanted to know whether content removal request  will affect our organic traffic.. Logically it shouldn't but still want to be sure before doing anything.

Comment: Our website cache is also very odd. Can this affect the SERP negatively? What can I do to correct it?

Comment: Removal request won't negatively affect organic traffic. If the request is accepted, it will only refresh their cache, snippet, etc. As for your second comment, could you create a new question and explain what you mean by "very odd"?

Comment: Hi .. Google my request for removal of outdated content without stating any specific reasons.